# Java - Colocar texto entre los valores de listas

Tags: java, string, jsf

Estoy usando el StrSubtitutor para crear partes de un documento que se vera en vista previa en una ventana con ckeditor. La cuestion se encuentra que necesito utilizar unas listas de objetos para los algunos datos y debe tener unos textos de por medio, explico con un ejemplo:

Patron de la cadena:

El(los) empleado(s)

```
 ${listaobjetos} 
 ${objeto.nombre}
```

con el codigo

```
 ${objeto.codigo}
```

realizo se logueo la ultima vez

```
 ${objeto.utimasesion} 
 ${finlistaobjetos}
```

Entonces descubri que en las librearias de apache commons tiene una clase llamada StrSubstitutor que me permite reemplazar variables en cadenas de texto y junto con StrLookup puedo cargar la lista de variables que tengo almacenadas en la BD, pero, en la documentacion este no especifica nada sobre estos casos. Intente activando las recursividades de StrSubstitutor sin ningun resultado.

De esta manera, acudo a ustedes para que me puedan guiar en esto porque tengo poca experiencia con este tipo de tratamiento de cadenas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que lo puedes resolver mediante la aplicación de un algoritmo que tu mismo puedes desarrollar, salvo que debes tener una estructura con parámetros para luego reemplazarlo por lo que necesitas.
Ejm:

```
public class Plantillas {

String documento = "empresa.Nombre\n"+
                   "empresa.Domicilio\n"+ 
                   "empresa.Ciudad, empresa.Pais\n"+

                    "Atte. D pto. de personal o Recursos Humanos Ciudad\n"+

                    "fecha.dia/fecha.mes/fecha.año\n"+
                    "Estimados señores:\n"+
                    "Por medio de la presente, dejo asentada mi decisión de terminar mi relación laborar con\n"+ 
                    "esta empresa a partir del DD/MM/AA\n"+

                    "Solo  me  motiva  esta  decisión  asuntos  profesionales  que  ustedes  seguramente  podrán"+ 
                    "comprender, pues necesito desarrollar mis habilidades como mis conocimientos para los" +
                    "que  me  he  formado  y  no puedo  perder  la  oportunidad  de  cumplir  mi  desarrollo"+ 
                    "profesional en otra empresa. Hoy  doy  a  conocer  esta  decisión  cumpliendo  con  el  plazo  que  establece  la  ley,  dos"+ 
                    "meses  antes  de  finalizar  mi  relación  laboral  el DD/MM/AA. Fecha  en  la  cual  ya  no" +
                    "perteneceré al personal de esta empresa. No obstante quiero dejarles en claro mi satisfacción por la confianza que han depositado"+ 
                    "en mí, durante el tiempo que pertenecí al personal con el que transcurrí mis días."+
                    "Les  agradezco  también  por  haberme  dado  la  o portunidad  de  conocer  la  gran  calidad"+ 
                    "humana de todo el personal de esta empresa, donde también pude desarrollarme.";

public void sustituirPalabrasClaves(){
    documento = documento.replaceAll("empresa.Nombre", "NESTLE");
    documento = documento.replaceAll("empresa.Domicilio", "Aragua");
    documento = documento.replaceAll("empresa.Ciudad", "Santa Cruz");
    documento = documento.replaceAll("empresa.Pais", "Venezuela");

    documento = documento.replaceAll("fecha.dia", "07");
    documento = documento.replaceAll("fecha.mes", "01");
    documento = documento.replaceAll("fecha.año", "2018");

    System.out.println("Texto final: \n"+documento);



}
```

Comment: Necesariamente tendria que ser una estructura de parametros ya que son diferentes tipos de reportes, pero esto tu respuesta me da una buena idea de lo que tengo que hacer. Gracias